# Работа с объектами в js, Как работать? Как вывести href?

Tags: javascript

Как работать с объектом в JS?
Получаю объект таким образом:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function()
    {
        var Test = $(this).parents('div').find('a');
    });
});
```

Для того что бы вывести `text()` пользуюсь такой конструкцией `console.log(Test.text());` с этим проблем нет, но когда пытаюсь вывести `href`, выводит `undefined` `console.log(Test.href);`

Comment: `console.log(Test[0].href);`  `console.log(Test.attr("href"));`

Answer (score 2):

Функция `jQuery` (она же - `$`) возвращает javascript-овый объект-обертку вокруг набора (возможно, пустого) DOM-элементов. У этой обертки есть методы и свойства, описаные в jQuery-API.

`href` - это свойство DOM-элемента с тэгом `а`. Добраться до него можно так:

```
console.log(Test[0].href); 
console.log(Test.attr("href"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю, что свойство `href` относится к тем свойствам, которые не всегда совпадают с атрибутом тега. В соответствии со [спецификацией](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#adef-href) W3C свойство `href` должно быть полной ссылкой. Поэтому, если нужно именно то, что было записано в атрибуте тега, следует воспользоваться методом `getAttribute`.

Например, для ссылки размещенной на странице по адресу `http://example.com`

`` <a href='/index.html'>Home</a>`
 console.log(test[0].href) // 'http://example.com/index.html'
 console.log(test[0].getAttribute('href')) // '/index.html' ``